# Discrete stochastic process to stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I was studying about stochastic processes and got stuck at a question.
Let's say, I have a stochastic process like the following,

$X_i(t+1)=\epsilon(X_i + X_j)$

$X_j(t+1)=(1-\epsilon)(X_i + X_j)$

where $\epsilon$ is a uniform random number $\in[0,1]$ and $i,j\in\{1,2,3,...,N\}$. I wanted to know if this process can be formulated in terms of $dX_i/dt$, with an unit of time being $N^2$.

Also is it possible to do this for any discrete stochastic process ? I mean, can any discrete stochastic process be casted into a corresponding stochastic differential equation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model is actually a well-known model in econophysics, it is called the *uniform reshuffling model*. A discrete time, discrete state space version of this model is studied, for instance, in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stephanie-Reed-9/publication/322221634_Rigorous_Results_for_the_Distribution_of_Money_on_Connected_Graphs/links/5e83c6c54585150839b2be20/Rigorous-Results-for-the-Distribution-of-Money-on-Connected-Graphs.pdf) by Nicolas Lanchier and Stephanie Reed. A continuous time, continuous state space version is studied in [a recent paper of myself](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.01302.pdf) (joint work with Pierre-Emmanuel Jabin and my Ph.D advisor Sebastien Motsch). In a [unpublished work by Roberto Cortez](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05372.pdf), the author used a coupling approach to study a generic binary exchange model which includes the uniform reshuffling dynamics as a special case, you may found the "SDE representation" (driven by Poisson random measures) in this work. (Spoiler: this is a hard paper to read)

Comment: Thank you very much for this very informative comment.

Comment: @SayanKundu If this meets what you need, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the "checkmark" symbol. Thank you!